# What can we expect when we culture a mould in a liquid?

Tags: mycology, fermentation

I am currently running a short project in my school, where I am trying to look into the biodegradation of dyes from textile effluents using *Fursarium* sp. Most of the articles that I have read uses a spore suspension as the seed, because it is easy to quantify, and also perhaps reproducible. Well, I was thinking about how vegetative cells, may have different metabolic traits, so what can I expect are the results if I use the vegetative cells as the seed? Also, if I were to use the vegetative cells as the seed, is it considered semi-quantitative if the seed (vegetative cell) is retrieved on an agar plug of equal diameter?

Comment: I expect the vegetative cells (mycelia) to grow much faster